# Easy way to log errors, etc to remote central location from .NET Compact Framework

Tags: logging, windows-mobile, compact-framework, analytics, metrics

I am looking for a very simple method for logging application errors and certain application metrics to a central remote location / server.

I'm thinking it will need to be something like Web Services or some similar technology.

One concern I have is device loses connectivity. I'd like to have something that stores the logs locally then forwards them. Ideally this would almost be transparent and seamless.

I could roll something of my own, but it seems like a very common need. I like to think there is an existing proven solution that I could take advantage of.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4Net works well on compact framework (for general logging), I don't think it provides remote centralised logging but you could build an appender that called a web service.

Also I seem to remember that MSPP had a logging application block as part of the [mobile client software factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480471.aspx#mcsflp_scbarchitecturetoolkit) that logged locally and then uploaded the logs to a central store when connectivity was available.

HTH

Matt